Error:  Build failed. @parcel/transformer-js: Browser scripts cannot have imports or exports
When doing npx parcel index.html and I had also setup the type=module in JS file. I've checked my Parcel configuration and verified the existence of the specified content key, but I'm still encountering this error. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this?
 Parcel encountered errors
Error: Expected content key de1e4a02ec63c4eb to exist
Error: Expected content key de1e4a02ec63c4eb to exist
at nullthrows (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\NAMASTE REACT!!\node_modules\nullthrows\nullthrows.js:7:15)
at AssetGraph.getNodeIdByContentKey (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\NAMASTE REACT!!\node_modules@parcel\graph\lib\ContentGraph.js:67:38)
at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\NAMASTE REACT!!\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\SymbolPropagation.js:52:82
at Array.map ()
at propagateSymbols (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\NAMASTE REACT!!\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\SymbolPropagation.js:52:61)
at AssetGraphBuilder.build (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\NAMASTE REACT!!\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\requests\AssetGraphRequest.js:174:62)
at async Object.run (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\NAMASTE REACT!!\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\requests\AssetGraphRequest.js:62:37)
at async RequestTracker.runRequest (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\NAMASTE REACT!!\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:673:20)
at async Object.run (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\NAMASTE REACT!!\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\requests\BundleGraphRequest.js:106:11)
at async RequestTracker.runRequest (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\NAMASTE REACT!!\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:673:20)
I first checked my Parcel setup to make sure it's correct. Then, I looked for the file it was asking for and made sure it's there. I also cleared Parcel's cache to start fresh. Even after all that, the error kept popping up. So, I read some instructions and ran Parcel in a detailed mode to see if that helps. I also asked for help in some online forums to see if others have had the same problem and found a solution.
